# Filament not sticking to bed/nozzle too high

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch

Brand new Ender 3 V2 Neo with CR Touch. Set printer up, switched on, ran bed levelling as per instructions, and tried first print.

Filament is not sticking to bed. I noticed that the nozzle is approx 5 mm above bed when printing. On this model there is no manual levelling, just auto. Any ideas?

Comment: 5 mm above the bed is **the** reason why it doesn't stick, maybe you need to explain what you did, it appears that you did do something (accidentally) not in accordance to the instructions. Please expand the question by [edit]. How did you slice the model, or did you use a model/G-code that came with the printer. The current question lacks too many details to answer; this generates very generic answers that may not help you fix the problem. Please [edit], thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to manually set the Z-probe offset in the Configuration. The CR-touch is mounted a little lower than the nozzle to prevent the nozzle from interfering when leveling. This offset is not fixed and may differ per installation.
I don't know the proper way to set this other than just incrementing values until the first layer is perfect. Starting you will increment with 1mm per test and in the end you will be incrementing with 0.1mm values. **One very big danger is though that setting a too high value, will press the nozzle into the printbed and damage both of them.** There for I don't recommend this method, but it is what works for me when being very careful with the increments.
Maybe someone with a good trick to safely set the probe offset can comment or answer here.

Comment: For the older Ender 3 (and likely this one too), home it first, then move the z-axis to the nominal zero position (display shows z=0; from the question this will be about 5mm above the bed). Setting the probe offset will then raise the nozzle in real-time. You’re looking for a negative value, so expect the final value to be approximately 5 less than whatever value is in there now. Save your settings afterwards. Ideally, redo the bed leveling and recheck the offset afterwards as well, and save again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks for all the great suggestions. Yes, it was the Z axis offset. After homing Z axis set to 10mm. Set this to zero hen carried out manual bed levelling. After this ran auto levelling then set Z axis offset to correct level. None of this is mentioned in the instal instructions. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve the issue! Happy printing! Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer of @Hacky as that answer has let you to the solution. Voting and accepting questions drives the community, thanks!